# Parsing generic ArrayList using GSON

Tags: java, generics, arraylist, gson

I'm having some trouble parsing a generic `ArrayList` with GSON. I've confirmed that this method works if the specific type for the `ArrayList` is specified (using no generics), but I'd like to write a method which works with generics.

Based on other stack overflow's questions, this should work, and I can't really understand why it doesn't. It fails to parse the `ArrayList` so all I get is a collection of `LinkedTreeMap`. The generic method is below:

```
public <T> List<T> listFromJson(@NonNull Class<T> classOfT ) throws JsonSyntaxException {
    if (data == null)
        return null;
    Gson gsonParser = new Gson();
    TypeToken<ArrayList<T>> token = new TypeToken<ArrayList<T>>() {};
    return gsonParser.fromJson(gsonParser.toJson(data), token.getType());
}
```

**Edit:** `data`is just an `Object`which contains the json to be parsed. The instruction `gsonParser.toJson(data)` works just fine.

And I'm calling it like this, where `MyClass` might be any custom java class I've written:

```
List<MyClass> resList = result.listFromJson(MyClass.class);
```

Any help would be appreciated, I don't really know what the problem is but it's related with the templates for sure, as a non generic method would do the work.

**Edit2:** Just to clarify, I'm also including the non generics method which worked:

```
public  List<MyClass> listFromJson() throws JsonSyntaxException {
        Type listType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<MyClass>>(){}.getType();
        Gson gsonParser = new Gson();
        return gsonParser.fromJson(gsonParser.toJson(data), listType);
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

When I set data to a `String[]` then both of your implementations work for me.
Are you using the same imports?
I am using this gson version `'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7'`

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.junit.Test;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException;
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;

public class SomeTest {

  private String[] data = { "Hello" };

  public <T> List<T> listFromJson(Class<T> classOfT) throws JsonSyntaxException {
    if (data == null)
      return null;
    Gson gsonParser = new Gson();
    TypeToken<ArrayList<T>> token = new TypeToken<ArrayList<T>>() {};
    return gsonParser.fromJson(gsonParser.toJson(data), token.getType());
  }

  public List<String> listFromJson() throws JsonSyntaxException {
    Type listType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<String>>(){}.getType();
    Gson gsonParser = new Gson();
    return gsonParser.fromJson(gsonParser.toJson(data), listType);
}

  @Test
  public void parsingGenericArrayListUsingGSON_0() {
    List<String> actual = listFromJson(String.class);
    List<String> expected = new ArrayList<>();
    expected.add("Hello");
    assertEquals(expected, actual);
  }

  @Test
  public void parsingGenericArrayListUsingGSON_1() {
    List<String> actual = listFromJson();
    List<String> expected = new ArrayList<>();
    expected.add("Hello");
    assertEquals(expected, actual);
  }
}
```

You also do not have to pass the `Class<T> classOfT` parameter.
Define the signature like this

```
 public <T> List<T> listFromJson() throws JsonSyntaxException
```

Comment: Hello, sorry for the long time without answering but I'm very busy these days.

I'm using gson version 1.19, managed from maven. I need to keep using this version. 

Please try to define a custom class with some attributes and test the method with it, It's not working for me. This post was originaly meant for android, but tested the method in Java and all I get is a LinkedHashMap<K,V> as a result of the parsing process... can't figure out why