# Save and Retrieving ArrayList to SharedPreferences

Tags: java, android, arraylist, sharedpreferences

This is my Saving Program Code this will save the score, date and the player name to the leaderboard:

```
mLeaderboardlist = new ArrayList<>();
   Leaderboardmodel s = new Leaderboardmodel();
   s.setDate("07/24/17");
   s.setName(player.getText().toString());
                    s.setScore(Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(yourScore.getText())));
            Tab1Normal.mLeaderboardlist.add(s);
            SharedPreferences appSharedPrefs = PreferenceManager
                            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
                    SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditor = appSharedPrefs.edit();
                    Gson gson = new Gson();
                    String json = gson.toJson(s);
                    prefsEditor.putString("MyObject", json);
                    prefsEditor.apply();
                    prefsEditor.commit();
```

And this is my retrieving program code of dealing also in sharedpreference:

```
 SharedPreferences appSharedPrefs = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this.getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String json = appSharedPrefs.getString("MyObject", "");
        Type type = new TypeToken<ArrayList<Leaderboardmodel>>(){}.getType();
        ArrayList<Leaderboardmodel> leaderboard= gson.fromJson(json, type);
            Collections.sort(leaderboard);
            adapter = new ListLeaderBoardAdapter(getActivity(), leaderboard);
            lvLeaderboardlist.setAdapter(adapter);
```

The save saving part work fines but the retrieving part display an error and makes the application crash, the error display :

> com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $

Comment: Did you try to put a breakpoint on `String json = appSharedPrefs.getString("MyObject", "");`, to see what it's there..?

Comment: what should i do sir?

Comment: check json contact with android debugger (use the debug..) see this link: https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you put an object, not a json.

```
Leaderboardmodel s = new Leaderboardmodel();
....
String json = gson.toJson(s);
prefsEditor.putString("MyObject", json);
```

You need to put your array

```
mLeaderboardlist = new ArrayList<>();
...
String json = gson.toJson(mLeaderboardlist );
```

Comment: when im doing that sir , there are no item display in retrieve part

Comment: You put array, you get array. You put object, you get object. Add objects to your list. You put object in `Tab1Normal.mLeaderboardlist.add(s);`, not `mLeaderboardlist.add(s);`. I don't know what you are doing.

Comment: how to retrieve that sir?

Comment: Retrieve what ?

Answer (score 0):

Change this line

```
ArrayList<Leaderboardmodel> leaderboard= gson.fromJson(json, type);
```

to this

```
Leaderboardmodel[] leaderboard= gson.fromJson(json, Leaderboardmodel[].class);
```

and see if it works.
I hope so.

Update:

You need to create an array list of Leaderboardmodel , then call sort.

```
ArrayList<Leaderboardmodel > leaderboardmodels = new ArrayList<>();
leaderboardmodels.addAll(leaderboard);
Collections.sort(leaderboardmodels);
```

Comment: then try this Leaderboardmodel[ ] leaderboard= gson.fromJson(json, Leaderboardmodel[ ].class);

Comment: its produce an error on Collection.sort(leaderboard);

Comment: Is it fixed sir?

Comment: yes sir , thankyou very much for all of your response ,, God Bless

Comment: Great.happy to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try to debug into your loaded `json` and see if you really get valid json String.

There is also already a similar question on so: [Parsing generic ArrayList using GSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39609761/parsing-generic-arraylist-using-gson)

Answer (score 0):

When you are saving you are saving object not arraylist,

```
String json = gson.toJson(s);
```

here s is object of Leaderboardmodel and not arraylist of Leaderboardmodel

So when you retrieve, retrieve it as object not array list like,

```
Type type = new TypeToken<Leaderboardmodel>(){}.getType();
Leaderboardmodel leaderboard= gson.fromJson(json, type);
```

Comment: That's an object, not a list.